# Remove items from listview on its ItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using a collection of ArrayList to fill my Listview. My ListView contains two separate rows types.

> Header and Footer.

I am trying to achieve the ExpandableListView Functionality on my Listview from which I am trying to remove some items on click of header till next header. 
I am using this function to loop through items and removing items

```
private void removeItems(int value)
{   Log.e(Constant.LOG, items.size()+"");
    for (int i = value;i < items.size(); i++) {
        if(!items.get(i).isSection())
            items.remove(i);
    }
    Log.e(Constant.LOG, items.size()+"");
    adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items, this);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

> QUESTION IS : I am not able to remove all items from the list in one shot, some stays there !

I have tried looping through adapter.count(); but no luck

My List :
SECTION 1
ITEM 1
ITEM 2
Item N
Section 2
But when I click on Section 1 not all ITEMS get deleted in one shot WHY!
I am not able to use Expandable Listview at this stage because activity contains many more complex functionality on List. Please help me where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `ArrayList<Collection>` , Then add your item in it and then use `removeAll(collection)`.

TRY THIS:

```
  private void removeItems(int value)
  {   Log.e(Constant.LOG, items.size()+"");
   ArrayList<Collection> deleteItems= new ArrayList<Collection>();

  for (int i = value;i < items.size(); i++) {
    if(!items.get(i).isSection())
       deleteItems.add(items.get(i));
}
 items.removeAll(deleteItems);
 Log.e(Constant.LOG, items.size()+"");
 adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items, this);
 mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

**EDIT**

Every time you are deleting an item, you are changing the index of the elements inside .

**e.g** :  let suppose you are deleting *list[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop?answertab=active#tab-top)* , then *list[2]* becomes *list[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop?answertab=active#tab-top)* and hence your code will skip *list[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop?answertab=active#tab-top)* next time because now your counter would be moved to 2.

Here are other ways by which you can achieve this also, 
[Removing item while iterating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Ohh there you go. I was using OLD List to update / remove items and forgot that its size is also changing. That another array List did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks mahn , See my answer below we have this as default . Arraylist remove and add all method use Iterator to add and remove item. ;)

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly I did now. Instead of looping through items again I did like this :

I created another list and parallely populate it with the main array.

```
items.add(user);
// after populating items did this
newItems.addAll(items);  // same collection ArrayList
```

and finally I can play with the main array by using removeAll and addAll methods.

```
items.removeAll(newItems);  // remove items
items.addAll(afterPosition,newItems); // add items after position
```