# How do I drop an item from a list when it doesn't have a specific name?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

How do I remove an item from a list if the item doesn't have an actual name?

I have a class that includes a method called `additem` that adds an `Item` object that I constructed in another class. The `Item` object has two parameters: `String name, String type`, which are the name of the item and the type of the item. Here is the code for the `additem` method:

```
public void additem(String name, String type){
    if("Weapon".equals(type)){
        itemlistweapons.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
    }
    else if ("Apparel".equals(type)){
        itemlistapparel.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
    }
    else if ("Aid".equals(type)){
        itemlistaid.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
    }
    else if ("Misc.".equals(type)){
        itemlistmisc.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
    }
}
```

So, when I add an item to the list in the main class, I do it like so:

```
items list = new items();

list.additems("Itemname", "Itemtype");
```

So I never actually give the Object a name to call upon. How could I have a method that removes that specific item from the list if the item was never identified? Is there a way I could identify the item by giving the object a name somehow?

Comment: When there is no item at all with that name, how can you remove it ?

Comment: Is there just one object without name? If multiple, which how do you tell which one you want?

Comment: The first parameter of the `Item` constructor *is* a name. I'm very confused why you say it doesn't have a name.

Comment: @dcsohl He probably means he passed an empty string. You can iterate over the list and find the one where name is null or empty.

Comment: By index in the list.

Comment: I mean I didn't identify it like this: Item name = new Item("itemname","itemtype"); Since I can't call upon 'Item name', how am I supposed to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Why not like this :-

```
public void removeitem(String name, String type) {

String checkItem = new Item(name, type).toString();

  for(int i = itemslistaid.size(); i > 0 ; i--)  {
    if(itemslistaid.get(i).equalsIgnorecase(checkItem))
         itemslistaid.remove(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is bad practice as it skips the item after a deleted item. Use an iterator instead or delete from the end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop

Comment: @Tobold Thank you, i Learned something new today, appreciate it, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

In java, your way to define an identifier to the an object in order to refer to it again is to override equals() and hashCode() methods for the object ... this is the way you can tell what object you are looking for thereafter

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to hold/find and "name" your lists, then it's just one line of code in your `add()` and `remove()` methods and it will automatically adapt to any number of named lists:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

public void additem(String name, String type) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(type);
}

public void removeitem(String name, String type) {
    Optional.ofNullable(map.get(name)).ifPresent(l -> l.remove(type));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the given code you are adding the string value of the object to a list

```
itemlistweapons.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
```

which is fine. but `toString` will not be returning a actual string if so
you can `override toString` method in your `Item` class

```
    class Item{

    public String toString(){
    return name+""+type;
    }

    }
```

now you a returning a actual string you can change it to return the any string from your class.

```
itemlistweapons.add(new Item(name, type).toString()); // this will contain string from toString method

itemlistweapons.remove(yourItem.toString); //this will remove item containing your string.
```