# Element not being recognised by IF statement

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to remove all elements that are triangles with the perimeter 12, I set up an if statement to check all the perimeters of the triangle objects out of an array list with a for loop.

My issue is when I run the for-loop it removes all the triangles with perimeters equal to 12 but the last one, it will still show up in the output.

Code:

```
double smallestTriangle = 0.0;
double biggestCircle = 0.0;

/*for loops to get the smallest triangle(12) and largest circle(63.xx)*/

for(int i = 0; i < ShapeList.size(); i++) {
    if (ShapeList.get(i).getClass().getName() == "Triangle") {
        System.out.println(ShapeList.get(i));
        System.out.println(ShapeList.get(i).getPerimeter() + " - " + smallestTriangle);
        if (ShapeList.get(i).getPerimeter() == smallestTriangle) {
            ShapeList.remove(i);
            System.out.println("REMOVED!");
        }
    }
    if (ShapeList.get(i).getClass().getName() == "Circle") {
        if (ShapeList.get(i).getPerimeter() == biggestCircle) {
            ShapeList.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Triangle {a=3.0 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.0
12.0 - 12.0
REMOVED!
Triangle {a=3.0 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.0
12.0 - 12.0
REMOVED!
Triangle {a=4.9 b=5.0 c=8.9} perimeter = 18.8
18.8 - 12.0
Triangle {a=3.1 b=4.1 c=5.1} perimeter = 12.299999999999999
12.299999999999999 - 12.0
Triangle {a=4.0 b=5.0 c=6.0} perimeter = 15.0
15.0 - 12.0
Triangle {a=3.1 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.1
12.1 - 12.0
Triangle {a=3.9 b=4.8 c=5.7} perimeter = 14.399999999999999
14.399999999999999 - 12.0
Circle {r=1.0} perimeter = 6.283185307179586
Circle {r=2.111} perimeter = 13.263804183456108
Circle {r=1.1} perimeter = 6.911503837897546
Triangle {a=3.9 b=4.0 c=5.9} perimeter = 13.8
Square {l=3.0} perimeter = 12.0
Rectangle {l=3.0 w=5.1} perimeter = 16.2
Square {l=5.0} perimeter = 20.0
Triangle {a=4.9 b=5.0 c=8.9} perimeter = 18.8
Rectangle {l=8.0 w=2.1} perimeter = 20.2
Circle {r=3.8} perimeter = 23.876104167282428
Triangle {a=3.1 b=4.1 c=5.1} perimeter = 12.299999999999999
Triangle {a=4.0 b=5.0 c=6.0} perimeter = 15.0
Rectangle {l=3.1 w=5.2} perimeter = 16.6
Circle {r=10.0} perimeter = 62.83185307179586
Triangle {a=3.1 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.1
Circle {r=2.0} perimeter = 12.566370614359172
Circle {r=3.0} perimeter = 18.84955592153876
Rectangle {l=3.0 w=5.2} perimeter = 16.4
Square {l=100.1} perimeter = 400.4
Square {l=100.2} perimeter = 400.8
Triangle {a=3.0 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.0 // <- not getting removed
Triangle {a=3.9 b=4.8 c=5.7} perimeter = 14.399999999999999
```

The array list:

```
Triangle {a=3.0 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.0
Circle {r=1.0} perimeter = 6.283185307179586
Circle {r=2.111} perimeter = 13.263804183456108
Circle {r=1.1} perimeter = 6.911503837897546
Triangle {a=3.0 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.0
Triangle {a=3.9 b=4.0 c=5.9} perimeter = 13.8
Square {l=3.0} perimeter = 12.0
Rectangle {l=3.0 w=5.1} perimeter = 16.2
Square {l=5.0} perimeter = 20.0
Triangle {a=4.9 b=5.0 c=8.9} perimeter = 18.8
Rectangle {l=8.0 w=2.1} perimeter = 20.2
Circle {r=3.8} perimeter = 23.876104167282428
Triangle {a=3.1 b=4.1 c=5.1} perimeter = 12.299999999999999
Triangle {a=4.0 b=5.0 c=6.0} perimeter = 15.0
Rectangle {l=3.1 w=5.2} perimeter = 16.6
Circle {r=10.0} perimeter = 62.83185307179586
Triangle {a=3.1 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.1
Circle {r=2.0} perimeter = 12.566370614359172
Circle {r=3.0} perimeter = 18.84955592153876
Rectangle {l=3.0 w=5.2} perimeter = 16.4
Square {l=100.1} perimeter = 400.4
Square {l=100.2} perimeter = 400.8
Circle {r=10.1} perimeter = 63.46017160251382
Triangle {a=3.0 b=4.0 c=5.0} perimeter = 12.0 //this element isn't getting removed
Triangle {a=3.9 b=4.8 c=5.7} perimeter = 14.399999999999999
```

Comment: Not sure this is part of the problem or not. But I would avoid `ShapeList.remove(i);` when looping over `ShapeList` . See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop) for example.

Comment: `ShapeList.get(23)` is the 24th element.

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 23, Size: 23` - Indexes are zero-based.  An array of size 23 has no index 23, only 0-22.

Comment: The arraylist has 25 items. I am guessing `remove()` removes two elements and therefore, when the index reaches to 23, the exception is thrown.

Comment: okay, I changed my example; even if I use i to loop through the code the triangle with perimeter 12 still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the arrayList got decreasing the size in every loop
for example if the arrayList size is 23  the next loop will be 22 in this case there is no index for 23, i suggest you to iterate the arrayList over `iterator` or make a backward loop starting with the last index ending with first index

Comment: I updated the code because I realized that was an issue, but my problem still remains about the element still existing, should be edited now.

Comment: did you iterate it over iterator ?
did you make a backward loop ?
i didn't see any update with the question :/ sorry

Comment: backward loop will be the best way for you :)

Comment: I ran it through debug mode and I couldn't see why it wasn't getting removed because in debug it said the if statement was true, could it be an ide error?

Comment: Nope, the debug is working fine, but as i told you if you  remove an element the the arrayList will be decreased the by size-1 in every loop 
if did you use backward loop then  the incidences will not be changed 
for example **arrayList has {1,3,5,6,7}** the index of 7 is 4 however if you did remove an element like 3, the index of 7 will be 3 not 4

Comment: you were correct thank-you, the backwords loop fixed it.

Comment: This is exactly what I said in the first comment!

Answer (score 1):

Do you also remove some circles ?

What seems to be happening is that each time you remove one shape from your list, you "skip" the next one. When you remove one element from the list, you decrement all subsequent element's indexes by one. So if you delete element 22, then the next element new index is 22, but you end up skiping it with a simple for loop.

What you can do is :

1. Change you for iteration to go backward (from higher index to 0)

`for(int i = ShapeList.size() - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {...}`

2. Recreate a new List of shapes containing the elements you want to keep and then discard the old list

Update: i reread your code and i'm pretty confindent that your problem is present when you have to delete two entity in a row. You remove the biggest circle right before your last triangle, so you skip it when you increment your index.
I agree with Basil Battikhi that resverse order for loop would be a perfect fit for your problem !

Comment: would a for-each loop suffice?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think java don't like removing element inside for each loops Edit : it will raise a ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: yah the removing elements in a loop incriminating upwards didn't go too well with java, going backwards did the trick. thank-you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after using array remove your elements are shifting to the left so your index i is skipping 1 value after every remove you make:
**Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).** For more info check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)). 
You can easily make another list with every not wanted elements position/index and remove them after.