# Element inside ArrayList fail to remove

Tags: java, arraylist

i have one arraylist `domainDailyData` which will stored the domain/apps data,please refer to the following

```
MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MIT0011, MBO/MBO0010, MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MOF0011, MIT/MIT0010]
```

i wish my program can count how many time of these element had occurred inside the arraylist, after that i will remove the counted element to avoid it's being count again and stored the extracted information into another arraylist call  `domainMonthlyData1` .But i found out some of the data inside `domainDailyData` weren't deleted away.
 This is my source code

```
               System.out.println("The domainDailyData before is :"+domainDailyData);
                int count11 = 0;
                for(int c = domainDailyData.size()-1;c>=0;c--)
                {     
                   String domainAndApps1 = domainDailyData.get(c);   //get the domain/apps out 
                   count11 = Collections.frequency(domainDailyData,domainAndApps1); // counting the number of occurrence 
                   System.out.println("Count of mail is :"+count11);
                   String [] splittedData = domainAndApps1.split(splitBy);  // the domain/apps 
                  // System.out.println(Emaildata1);
                   String domain1 = splittedData [0];
                   String apps1 = splittedData[1];
             //      System.out.println("The extracted domain is :"+domain1);  // display domain
               //    System.out.println("The extracted apps is :"+apps1);  // display apps
                   domainMonthlyData1.add(domain1); 
                   domainMonthlyData1.add(apps1);   //add into arraylist 
                   domainMonthlyData1.add(String.valueOf(count11));  //add into arraylist
                   Iterator<String> it1 = domainDailyData.iterator();
                   while(it1.hasNext())   // remove the counted domain/apps
                     {
                          String domainAndApps2 = it1.next();
                          if(domainAndApps1.equals(domainAndApps2))
                          {
                           it1.remove();
                           c--;
                           }
                     }
                 }
                System.out.println("The domainDailyData after is :"+domainDailyData);
                System.out.println("The domainMonthlyData1 is :"+domainMonthlyData1);
```

This is my sample output from my program

```
The domainDailyData before is :MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MIT0011, MBO/MBO0010, MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MIT0010, MIT/MOF0011, MIT/MIT0010]
Count of mail is :2
Count of mail is :5
The domainDailyData after is :[MIT/MIT0011, MIT/MOF0011]
The domainMonthlyData1 is :[MBO, MBO0010, 2, MIT, MIT0010, 5]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete data from ArrayList with a For-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop)

Comment: Although you are deleting the `ArrayList` by using `Iterator`, however, your outer loop is still keep using the _old_ index before deletion.

Comment: @Alex how to modify it? i search the solution in stackoverflow and come to this stage

Comment: @Berger Thanks for the link, i will have a look on it. Between, i also search the solution in stackoverflow before i come to this stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may always get the first element of the list to do the count. As it will be deleted by your later `Iterator` loop, you may safely get the first element again in the next iteration for the next element to count.

Therefore, you code will be like below.

```
while (domainDailyData.size() > 0)
{
    String domainAndApps1 = domainDailyData.get(0);
    // your logic
    Iterator<String> it1 = domainDailyData.iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext())   // remove the counted domain/apps
    {
        String domainAndApps2 = it1.next();
        if(domainAndApps1.equals(domainAndApps2))
        {
            it1.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very helpful