# Arraylist Pang Game , Arrow class

Tags: java, arraylist

When i shoot the arrow and its hits the bubble a few times , its generates on a random moment a lot of arrows and crashed i cant find why this happens

for (int i = 0; i < bubblesArray.size(); i++) {

```
bubblesArray.get(i).move();
bubblesArray.get(i).checkBorders();
bubblesArray.get(i).display();

if (bubblesArray.get(i).checkHit(p)) {
}

for (int j = 0; j < arrowArray.size(); j++) {

  arrowArray.get(j).shoot();
  arrowArray.get(j).display();

  // verwijderd array wanneer die buiten scherm komt

    if (arrowArray.get(j).getPosYArrow()+arrowArray.get(j).getHeightArrow() < 0) {
      arrowArray.remove(j);

  }

  // verwijder array wanneer die tegen bubble zit

  if (bubblesArray.get(i).checkHitArrow(arrowArray.get(j))) {
    timesHit+=1;
    numberOfBubble*=2;

   if(arrowArray.size()>=0){
    arrowArray.remove(j);
   }
    // aanmaken nieuwe bubble
    bubbleWidth = bubble.width/2;
    bubbleHeight = bubble.height/2;
    bubble.resize(bubbleWidth, bubbleHeight);

    for ( int k = 0; k < numberOfBubble; k++) {

      bubblesArray.add(new Bubbles(bubblesArray.get(i).getPosXBubbles(), bubblesArray.get(i).getPosYBubbles(), bubble));
    }
    bubblesArray.remove(i);
  }
}
```

}
}

void keyPressed() {

if (key == ' ') {

```
arrowArray.add(new Arrow(arrow, p.getPosXPlayer()+p.getWidthPlayer()/2, p.getPosYPlayer()));
printArray(arrowArray);
```

}
}

erros and draw error; https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaMqq.jpg

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: Check this question, if it isn't the current problem you have, it may well be the next one :)  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop

Comment: `if (bubblesArray.get(i).checkHit(p)) {
    }`     What is this for?

Comment: checking if the player is hit by the bubble

Answer (score 0):

You call remove from array while iterating it.

```
arrowArray.remove(j);
```

So it will throw `ConccurrentModificationException`.
If you want to remove while iterating over a list, don't use `forEach`. Let use iterator.

```
Iterator<YourObject> iterator = arrowArray.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
 YourObject obj = iterator.next();
 // Test with obj
 if (your conjdition) {
       iterator.remove();//It's safe
 }
}
```

Do it with your `bubblesArray.remove(i);` too

Comment: i use prossecing to code so and iterator is avaible in this program