# Deleting all selected items in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to delete multiple items from recyclerView. The items in the recyclerView has an attribute `isSelected`. I am setting the attribute `isSelected` to `true` when user clicks on the recyclerView item. After selection user can click `delete` button present in the options menu to delete the selected items. The code has unexpected behaviour, like when `delete` button is pressed, some of the selected items are deleted while some are not. Also some of the items get automatically selected at random positions.

**Model.java**

```
public class Model {
    private String text;
    private boolean isSelected = false;

    public Model(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }


    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Model> mModelList;
    private Context mCtx;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context ctx, List<Model> modelList) {
        this.mModelList = modelList;
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Model model = mModelList.get(position);
        holder.view.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
        holder.tvItems.setText(model.getText());
        holder.tvItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
                holder.tvItems.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mModelList == null ? 0 : mModelList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvItems;
        private View view;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            tvItems = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItems);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Model> mModelList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvListItems);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, getListData());
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private List<Model> getListData() {
        mModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
            mModelList.add(new Model("TextView " + i));
        }
        return mModelList;
    }


    private void deleteSelectedItems() {
        if (mModelList != null){
            for (int i=0; i<mModelList.size(); i++){
                if (mModelList.get(i).isSelected()){
                    Log.d("testingTAG", String.valueOf(i));
                    mModelList.remove(i);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(i, mModelList.size());
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_delete:
                deleteSelectedItems();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just remove i-- then try

Comment: @milan pithadia no chance

Comment: For Kotlin users, the following article might be useful [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166).

Answer (score 1):

You should use holder.getAdapterPosition() inside your clicklistener .Change your onclick as given below and try.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                final Model model = mModelList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
                holder.tvItems.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @pop selects items, change background color to CYAN if item is selected  and inverse selected flag of Model class instance.

you should delete selected items from your mModelList using a iterator, you can't delete items from list inside for loop

[Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)

Comment: @Thracian the logic used by him is correct, not optimized but correct.

Comment: @nitinkumarp No, it's not. Let say list has 3 items. Index starts at 0 and ends in 2. He lowers i-- but loop will run until i is 2 to but there won't be mModelList.get(2) since now list contains 2 elements. Correct way to remove from a list is to use iterator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop

Comment: @Thracian don't you think the condition `i<mModelList.size()` inside for loop  takes care of it? One more thing I even tried to solve the problem using _iterator_ but couldn't get it right.

Comment: @nitinkumarp why do you say it is not optimized? Could you please point out mistakes and if possible provide an efficient method.

Comment: @MONUKUMAR To test, create a list of 3 items. If your final i value before i-- is 2 after removing an item from the list, app will crash because your list won't have item with index 2 mList.get(2) won't exist. Check out the links i posted.

Comment: @Thracian, `i=2` implies the condition inside `if` was never true. Now when `i = 2` you say, the condition inside `if` becomes true and so on. I don't think that's a problem. item at index `2` will be removed and finally value `i` will be `1`. Also the app doesn't crash. I have tested it.

Comment: To optimize your `for` use `else` statement and write `++i` inside else. Remove i++ from for statement `for (int i=0; i<mModelList.size();)` and remove `i--`.