# i have trouble with removeDuplicate() method

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, shapes

my code looks correct but when i run it has a bug(ArrayIndexOutOfBound).

```
my Main method:

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Diagram d1 = new Diagram();
    Layer l1 = new Layer();
    Shape s1 = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);
    Shape s2 = new Circle(10);
    Shape s3 = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);
    Shape s4 = new Rectangle(10, 5);
    l1.layers.add(s1);
    l1.layers.add(s2);
    l1.layers.add(s3);
    l1.layers.add(s4);
    d1.diagrams.add(l1);

//        l1.deleteTriangle();
//        System.out.println(l1.layers.get(0));

    l1.deleteDuplicate();
    System.out.println(l1.layers);
```

when i try commenting hexagon and shape parts, my code build successfully but it remove most of my Shape

Comment: `i`? `j`? Where do these come from? Is there some `for` loops that you didn't show us?

Comment: shry, when i added , it requested fewer code

Comment: 'if (layers.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < layers.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < layers.size(); j++) {'

Comment: You should edit the question instead of adding these as comments.

Comment: From the deleteDuplicate code posted earlier, when the first `if` evaluates true, element `j` is removed. In the next block, element `j` is fetched again. Now, if `j` was the index of the last element in the Layer, then the second `if` will try to reference beyond the bounds of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "same shape", the more organized way to fix this could be to override `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) in each of the "shape" subclasses.

Example using `Triangle` class.

```
public class Triangle extends Shape {
    // The normal triangle stuff

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int ret = getA();
        ret *= 31;
        ret += getB();
        ret *= 31;
        ret += getC();
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Triangle other = (Triangle) obj;

        return getA() == other.getA() &&
               getB() == other.getB() &&
               getC() == other.getC();
    }
}
```

To get a new list (set) without duplicates:

```
List<Shape> shapes = Arrays.asList(new Triangle(3, 4, 5), new Triangle(4, 4, 5), new Triangle(3, 4, 5));

Set<Shape> shapesWithoutDuplicates = new HashSet<>(shapes);
```

You should only do this *if* it is *natural* for triangles having the same dimension to be "equal". If it is only "naturally equal" if the triangles are also drawn at the same spot, then this particular attempt to remove "duplicates" would be a special one-off case.

Using your original method, you are getting the exception because you are trying to evaluate after you have removed something.

See [Delete data from ArrayList with a For-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop).