# Am I able to do this for loop in my code to pull out different values?

Tags: java

For my code I am trying to keep track of infection levels for different cities for a homework assignment.  When I add one to these values for some reason they don't workout when I run it through this for loop. I am wondering how I could fix this code to make it work and run better.  Here is my main for loop that runs the main part I am trying to fix.

```
public static void checkInf() {
        for (int i = 0; i < citiesInfected.length(); i++) {
            if(citiesInfected.getValue(i).getInfectionLevel() == 1){
            citiesInfected.remove(i);
                City newPop = citiesInfected.getValue(i);
                int popRounded = (int) (newPop.getPopulation() * .9);
                int realPopRound = popRounded + 1;
                newPop.setPopulation(realPopRound);
                citiesInfected.add(citiesInfected.getValue(i));
            }
            else if (citiesInfected.getValue(i).getInfectionLevel() == 2) {
                citiesInfected.remove(i);
                City newPop = citiesInfected.getValue(i);
                int popRounded = (int) (newPop.getPopulation() * .8);
                int realPopRounded = popRounded +1;
                newPop.setPopulation(realPopRounded);
                citiesInfected.add(citiesInfected.getValue(i));

            }
            else if (citiesInfected.getValue(i).getInfectionLevel() == 3) {
                citiesInfected.remove(i);
                City newPop = citiesInfected.getValue(i);
                int popRounded = (int) (newPop.getPopulation() * .75);
                int realPopRound = popRounded + 1;
                String newName = "New " + citiesInfected.getValue(i).getCityName();
                newPop.setPopulation(realPopRound);
                int pop = (int) (citiesInfected.getValue(i).getPopulation() * .75);
                int populationRounded = pop + 1;
                int newInfectionLevel = 0;
                City newCity = new City(newName, populationRounded, newInfectionLevel);
                citiesInfected.add(newCity);

                citiesInfected.add(citiesInfected.getValue(i));
                System.out.println(newCity.getCityName() + " has been made.");
            }
            else if (citiesInfected.getValue(i).getInfectionLevel() == 4) {
                citiesQuarantined.add(citiesInfected.getValue(i));
                System.out.println(citiesInfected.getValue(i).getCityName() + " has been placed in 
quarantine!");
            }
            else return;
        }
    }
```

I am giving it these inputs for the cities the last numbers being the infection levels.

```
b,2310,2
r,1967,1
e,3167,2
n,781,0
d,6706,0
a,2902,2
nn,8234,3
```

When I add one to all of those last numbers I want each of the numbers to do a different action(the actions being the ones in the for loop). Basically I am just confused if my for loop is messed up which is why I am getting the wrong input, or if it is something different. I really hope this makes sense. Here is also the output of my code.

```
The infection level for all cities has been increased.
New r has been made.
New n has been made.
nn has been placed in quarantine!
```

I want it to say:

```
New b has been made.
New e has been made.
New a has been made.
```

Because all of these are at infection level 2

Comment: This may address your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop Also, your code would be clearer if instead of using `if ... else if ...` etc. you used a `switch` statement.

Comment: Could you add the code that creates the `citiesInfected` list? I'm puzzled by the last line in your actual output, since it doesn't seem there are any input lines with the value 4. Apart from that your loop problem looks identical to the one mentioned in the previous comment. You're deleting elements from the list you're using. You're actually using the next element, because you've deleted the "current" index element.