# How to delete certain cards that has been used from player hand in Java?

Tags: java

I am programming the game in Java. I am using Java ArrayList to store the cards. But do a ignore case string check on the cards, the problem is it is deleting the cards with the name "Trooper", but it always leave one trooper card in the player hand. I wanted it to leave all trooper cards.

Card Display in Java Console: Trooper Agent Agent Agent Trooper Trooper
Jave Code:

```
if(mouseCursor.getRectangle().intersects(placeList.get(i).getRectangle()) && mouseCursor.isPressed() ) {
    if(attackPower >= placeList.get(i).getAttackPower()) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < playerDisplayDeck.size();j++) {
            System.out.println(playerDisplayDeck.get(j).getName());
        }
        for(int j = 0 ; j < playerDisplayDeck.size();j++) {
            if(playerDisplayDeck.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("trooper")) {
                playerDisplayDeck.remove(j);
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0 ; j < playerDisplayDeck.size();j++) {
            System.out.println(playerDisplayDeck.size());
        }
        attackPower = attackPower - placeList.get(i).getAttackPower();
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to fire up your favorite IDE's debugger, use it to step through your code, inspect key variables as you step, and find out why the problem is occurring.

Comment: look here maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop

Comment: @Progman thank very much for that link. Fixed it and understand why now!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way you are removing the troopers from the List. By counting up in the array and removing from the list your making the size of `playerDisplayDeck` smaller but `j` stays the same. To fix this you should start the `for loop` with `playerDisplayDeck.size() -1` and decrese it, insted of starting the loop with 0 and increasing it.

Like this:

```
for(int j = playerDisplayDeck.size() -1 ; j >= 0;j--) {
    if(playerDisplayDeck.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("trooper")) {
        playerDisplayDeck.remove(j);
    }
}
```