# Object is not getting removed from ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, collections

There is a generic tree data structure. Now, It's Node Class will look something like this.

```
private static class Node {
    int data;
    ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

The formation of DS is being solely structured by taking inputs. Now what I need to perform is to remove all the leaf nodes. The below code is unable to remove children which are already present in the instance member of it.

```
public static void removeLeaves(Node node) {
ArrayList<Node> nodeChildrenList = node.children;
int childrenSize = nodeChildrenList.size();
for(int i = 0; i < childrenSize; i++){
    Node child = nodeChildrenList.get(i);
    removeLeaves(child);
    if(child.children.size() == 0){
        child.children.remove(child); // Problem
    }
}
}
```

I can't able to understand the object(Node) child is not getting removed from ArrayList. But Iterator is working fine. I have even tried debugging at each step. When the breakpoint reaches child.children.remove(child); line. It doesn't complete it.

While this code is working like charm.

```
    ArrayList<Node> nodeChildrenList = node.children;
    // int childrenSize = nodeChildrenList.size();
    Iterator itr = nodeChildrenList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
       Node child = (Node)itr.next();
       if(child.children.size() == 0){
           itr.remove();
       }
       removeLeaves(child);
    }
    // for(int i = 0; i < childrenSize; i++){
    //     Node child = nodeChildrenList.get(i);
    //     removeLeaves(child);
    //     if(child.children.size() == 0){
    //         child.children.remove(child);
    //     }
    // }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete data from ArrayList with a For-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738634/delete-data-from-arraylist-with-a-for-loop)

Comment: For one, your for loop is calling ```child.children.remove(child)``` when the size of the ```child.children``` arraylist is 0. It's already empty. For another, use iterators to modify in-place, not for-each loops. The latter can produce [ConcurrenctModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) or worse, non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: Perhaps you meant ``if (child.children.size() > 0)``

Comment: Why you want to remove something from a list when the list is empty ? And why are you  trying to remove from the children list of a node the node itself ?

Comment: @NomadMaker I bet OP actually meant that if the child has no children, remove the child itself from its parent, i.e. `if (child.children.isEmpty()) { nodeChildrenList.remove(child); }` --- But, the recursive call doesn't make any sense, because the method ends up removing *all* descendant nodes.

Comment: @Gryphon The list is not empty It will get filled by taking inputs.

Comment: @Andreas Quite right

Comment: @HimanshuSharma ```if(child.children.size() == 0){
        child.children.remove(child); // Problem
    }``` (as it is written in your code) is attempting to remove an element from a list only if that list is empty (which ends up doing nothing). It would probably go a long way to edit your question and tell us exactly what you want the code to do. Better to know what you want than to have us guess and clutter up the comments =) Then we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question.

Comment: @Gryphon Hope now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what your removeLeaves with the for loop is doing. Added comments below

```
ArrayList<Node> nodeChildrenList = node.children;
int childrenSize = nodeChildrenList.size();
for(int i = 0; i < childrenSize; i++){    // Loop through each of node's children
    Node child = nodeChildrenList.get(i); // Get the child of node at index i
    removeLeaves(child);                  // recursively call removeLeaves with the child
    if(child.children.size() == 0){       // If the node's child has no children
        // This is a problem because you are telling the program to remove the node's 
        // child from the node's child's children, not from the node's children.
        child.children.remove(child);     
    }
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense, you are calling `remove` on the wrong list. To do what you want, you would want to call `node.children.remove(child)` since you want to remove the node's child from the list of the node's children.

However, this also causes problems, because now you have altered the structure you are looping through. For instance, let's look at a very simple case.

```
         1
        / \
       2   3
```

In this case, we have a root node with value 1 and two children.
The first child has a value 2 and no children.
The second child has a value of 3 and no children.

So if we walk through the `removeLeaves` method line by line, let's see what happens.

when called with the root node:

```
ArrayList<Node> nodeChildrenList = node.children; // nodeChildrenList contains two nodes - the ones with values 2 and 3

int childrenSize = nodeChildrenList.size(); // childrenSize is 2
for(int i = 0; i < childrenSize; i++){  // Start with i = 0
    Node child = nodeChildrenList.get(i); // The first child is the one with value 2
    removeLeaves(child);  // Call remove leaves again with the child with value 2
```

We'll come back to this iteration of the method later, now we dive in again with the first child

```
ArrayList<Node> nodeChildrenList = node.children; // The first node has no children, so this is an empty list
int childrenSize = nodeChildrenList.size(); // size is 0
for(int i = 0; i < childrenSize; i++){  // None of this gets called
    Node child = nodeChildrenList.get(i);
    removeLeaves(child);
    if(child.children.size() == 0){
        node.children.remove(child); 
    }
}
```

now that we've exited from the first child (with value 2), we finish up the loop iteration with the root node

```
    if(child.children.size() == 0){ // child is still the first child (value 2), and it doesn't have any children, so this is true
        node.children.remove(child); // So we remove it from the root node's children. 
    }
}
```

Now we have a root node with one child (the one with value 3) Great, right? Well, not so much. Since we've modified the structure we are looping through, we'll encounter an issue. Let's walk through the next iteration of the loop with the root node's children.

```
for(int i = 0; i < childrenSize; i++){  // i = 1 and childrenSize of the root node is 2, so we can continue
    Node child = nodeChildrenList.get(i); // Uh oh, we don't have a child at index 1!
```

The problem here is that since there were structural modifications to nodeChildrenList, there is now only one element in the list (at index 0) - the element with value 3. There is no element at index 1, so this throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException. This is why you want to use an iterator when making structural modifications to a collection you are looping through.

Comment: Really thanks, man. If I remove the child from the start then other nodes will get shifted, That will also be solved if I iterate the list from the end. And yeah child.children.remove was indeed a blunder.

Comment: Yep, you definitely could work backwards and have this case work. Just make sure to move ```removeLeaves``` after the call to ```node.children.remove```, otherwise you end up with only the root node left.